Block specific robots/bots from visiting the site
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Bytespider; spider-feedback@bytedance.com)
.htaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (SemrushBot|MJ12bot|AhrefsBot|DotBot|Bytespider|Photon|Spawning-AI|GPTBot|ImagesiftBot|BLEXBot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]

I don't quite understand this rule, what it does. In theory it should save from bots...
But in reality it doesn't help...
How to make it so that if HTTP_USER_AGENT contains an entry from the listed keys. In this case block, close the site...
At the moment, for example, the Bytespider bot. Still visits the site...
I write down the HTTP_USER_AGENT value of each visit and see that this bot visits the site...
Perhaps the rule is written incorrectly, there is an error, the register is involved, or something else.

The rule sounds correct, any request with User Agent containing any of the stings in the list will be forbidden. Maybe it's not placed correctly in the htaccess (or you are not looking in the correct htaccess file)
